# How to derive Clone and Copy on struct with a vector?

Tags: rust, vector, hashmap, clone

I feel this problem requires maybe a simple trait annotation, but I am stuck. I want to create clones of these structs during the other part of the program.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct NodeMap {
    map: HashMap<usize, Node>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Node {
    destinations: Vec<usize>,
    visits_left: usize,
}
```

Everything should be clonable. But it says that `Vec<usize>` nor `HashMap<usize, Node>` do not implement `Copy`. I must be missing something because it seems like this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) explains this quite well. `Copy` means **bitwise** copy (i.e. cheap), not copy at any cost (as you could implement in C++ for example, allocate a new storage...). On the other hand, `Clone` is explicit on the intention; the cost of duplicating data can be read in the source code at the exact point where this clone is made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap` and `Vec` do not implement `Copy` - they can't be cloned via a bitwise copy.

That means neither can your structs.

You can derive `Clone` without `Copy`. Just do that.